# grails clean way to replace null values with empty string

Tags: grails

In Grails, what is the cleanest way to convert null domain fields to empty string "" for example when returning a list from controller to view. Because i have many allowed nullable fields, all these "null" values are visible in my table on the gsp.

Is there a shorthand for this or should i add a javascript method on the view that will replace all "null" with empty string?

Comment: If it is just a view concern you can also add a tag(-library) and wrap the fields just there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override a getter, example

```
class MyDomain {
    String myNullableField

    String getMyNullableField() {
        return this.@myNullableField ?: ''
    }
}
```

and still use it just by the field name

or maybe better, you can create additional getter:

```
    static transients = ['myNullableFieldNullSafe']

    String getMyNullableFieldNullSafe() {
        return this.myNullableField ?: ''
    }
```

and use it like: `myDomainObject.myNullableFieldNullSafe`